# how to check for opened ports on a wifi router

Tags: tcp, wireshark, router

I want to check remotely if a specific port is opened on a wifi router.
How can I do that?

Do I need to set something on the router side?

I tried using telnet but I get Unable to connect to remote host.

Comment: Why don't use a port scanner?

Comment: remotely? or on the router?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scan with [PortScan](http://thesz.diecru.eu/content/portscan.php) your Router-IP. Think this should work for you.

Switch scan type to "Scan All Ports". In this case I simply scanned the local host. Change localhost to your Router IP.

[image]

Comment: thx for your replay. I want to check port 10006 which i see in the sip header ip:port. When I use portScan the port seems to be closed...but with sip I am able to send an outgoing call on that ip:port. What could be the reason why I can t see the port open when checking with this app?

Answer (score 5):

On ubuntu: `sudo apt-get install nmap; nmap -vv <router-ip>`